# Unit of Work with Identity on ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-core, unit-of-work

I'm creating web api for a mobile application, I need when user registering add the data to database, I want to add the data to multiple tables

My User table design :

- AspnetUsers : Default identity table
- StudentUsers: The second table of user detail
- TeacherUsers: Third table for user

When on registering, user selecting which they're student or teacher.
The problem here is, there is two table when registering, I want to use Unit of Work for that situation, to prevent data saving fails. If data fails not to add the data to other table.

But how can I implement this into identity?

Comment: Have you chosen your ORM yet?  (Entity Framework Core is usual suspect)

Comment: I'm Using EF Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to overthink/overdo Unit Of Work with Entity Framework Core.

See:

https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/

So to get your "transaction", you will call

```
myInjectedContext.BeginTransaction().
/* alter any/all of the 3 DbSets */
    myInjectedContext.Commit();
```

where myInjectedContext is a IDataContext.

```
public class MyTransactionallyFriendlyDbContext : DbContext /*(, IDataContext) */
{
    public LasteDbContext(DbContextOptions<LasteDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
 
    public DbSet<AspnetUser> AspnetUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StudentUser> StudentUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TeacherUser> TeacherUsers { get; set; }
    
    private IDbContextTransaction _transaction;
 
    public void BeginTransaction()
    { 
        _transaction = Database.BeginTransaction();
    }
 
    public void Commit()
    {
        try
        {
            SaveChanges();
            _transaction.Commit();
        }
        finally
        {
            _transaction.Dispose();
        }        
    }
 
    public void Rollback()
    { 
        _transaction.Rollback();
        _transaction.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Here is an interface to satisfy Ioc/Unit Testing needs.

```
public interface IDataContext
{
    DbSet<AspnetUser> AspnetUsers { get; set; }
    DbSet<StudentUser> StudentUsers { get; set; }
    DbSet<TeacherUser> TeacherUsers { get; set; }
 
    void BeginTransaction();
    void Commit();
    void Rollback();
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I'm a NHibernate guy, but I'm working on  overcoming my fear for EF :-)  A question: Is it possible that SaveChanges(); can cause an exception which in turn will require a rollback? I would appreciate to see an example of usage of MyTransactionallyFriendlyDbContext #Rollback().

Comment: NHibernate UoW is the exact thing I was thinking of .. in regards to (not to) "overdo".     I seldom call or actually code for a Rollback, its just there, just in case.  EFCore (like most things dotnet core 3+) is very clean.  Its a rewrite (dotnetFW) of a rewrite( C#/Anders/Java).    EFCore has won me over.  The article explains the motivations fairly well.